# Sonargraph integration - FAILED To iniatialize JAXB

Tags: jaxb, sonarqube

I am having trouble integrating sonarqube with sonargraph.

In the computer engine logs it shows the following information:

Sonargraph Integration: Failed to load built in meta data from '/com/hello2morrow/sonargraph/integration/sonarqube/ExportMetaData.xml' - Failure: Load data from stream
Error - Read Error. Failed to initialize JAXB
2019.12.11 15:07:33 ERROR ce [AW717h0MnoxPx5q7V62B] [o.s.c.t.CeWorkerImpl] Failed to perform task AW717h0MnoxPx5q7V62B

Someone can help me.

Sonarqube 8
AWS T3 Large
Java 11

Answer (score 0):

This problem was caused by a change in SonarQube and has already been fixed in December. Details can be found in the issue tracker of the plugin's official GitHub repo https://github.com/sonargraph/sonar-sonargraph-integration/issues/19 .

To get a faster reponse to problems in the future, please file a bug report there or send an email to support at hello2morrow.com .